# Как связать два языка в один проект

Tags: python, golang, telegram

задался вопросом, каким образом можно связать два языка в одном проекте.
Меня интересуют конкретно Golang и Python, я хочу написать телеграмм бота, который будет парсить большой обьем информации с нескольких сайтов.
Но реализация самого бота в Golang меня не очень устраивает, я бы хотел наваять "движок" бота на Python, а спаршенную инфу получать из Golang, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие способы реализации есть?

Comment: Микросервисная арихтектура в чистом виде: две независимых программы и унифицированный вариант обмена данными. Обмен данными можно реализовать посредством очереди (RabbitMQ, redis).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы всегда можете написать маленькое приложение на go, которое будет парсить файл с данными и складывать данные в другой. А питоновый скрипт будет подготавливать этот файл и запускать приложение. При этом абсолютно все равно, на каком языке написаны оба приложения.

Да, вместо файлов можно использовать сокеты, пайпы или общую память. Но это детали реализации.

Второй способ - это создать библиотеку (dll/[so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757090/shared-library-in-go)) и использовать в питоне. На [хабре есть статья на эту тему](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/324250/) ([оригинал](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf)). Результат этого все - в питоне "появятся новые функции", которые Вы сможете использовать как обычные функции.

**UPD**

Ну и самый "извращенный" - никто не мешает на go написать http сервер, а с питона вызывать. Пока это на одной машине - выглядит дико, но если go сервер поставить на отдельный сервер за load balancer, то все может заиграть новыми красками.